# Creating a chart of datagridview

Tags: c#, winforms, arraylist, charts

Chart type: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.chart(v=vs.110).aspx

Case: Create chart by datagridview.

Datagridview code(works):

```
//Datagrid
data.Location = new Point(200, 75);
data.Size = new Size(600, 400);
data.BackgroundColor = Color.White;
data.Font = new Font("Times New Roman", 14.0f);

//Columns
data.ColumnCount = 2;
data.ColumnHeadersVisible = true;
DataGridViewCellStyle columnHeaderStyle = new DataGridViewCellStyle();
columnHeaderStyle.BackColor = Color.White;
columnHeaderStyle.Font = new Font("Verdana", 10, FontStyle.Bold);
data.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle = columnHeaderStyle;

// Set the column header names.
data.Columns[0].Name = "ID";
data.Columns[1].Name = "Value";

//Width of  columns
DataGridViewColumn column = data.Columns[0];
column.Width = 279;
DataGridViewColumn column1 = data.Columns[1];
column1.Width = 278;

//Add datagridview
tabpage2.Controls.Add(data);
```

Image of datagridview:
[Datagridview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EjOwf.png)

For testing i've got this so far:

This code update the chart and updates if button is clicked.

```
private void createChart()
{
    chart.Size = new Size(600, 400);
    chart.Location = new Point(100, 100);
    chart.BackColor = Color.Blue;
    chart.BorderlineColor = Color.Black;
    chart.Series.Add("test");
    chart.Series["test"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Bar;

    Button button = new Button();
    button.Size = new Size(50,50);
    button.Text = "moi";
    button.Location = new Point(0,0);
    button.Click += (sender, args) =>
    {
        updateChart();
    };
    tabpage3.Controls.Add(button);
    tabpage3.Controls.Add(chart);
}
```

this method updates the chart:

```
private void updateChart()
{
    chart.Series[0] = new Series();
    chart.Series[0].XValueMember = data.Columns[0].DataPropertyName;
    chart.Series[0].YValueMembers = data.Columns[1].DataPropertyName;
    chart.DataSource = data.DataSource;
}
```

I would like to achieve a bar chart of these values.

I've never used charts in C# before, thanks for help!

Comment: Trying to achieve a line chart.             chart.Series["test"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;

Comment: I dont know what you mean.. this is how i create it         Chart chart = new Chart();

Comment: So this type - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.chart(v=vs.110).aspx ? Could you create a https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve so we can quickly set it up on our end?

Comment: Sorry, im kind of new with stackoverflow, what more information are you looking for? Edit the question and put the chart type in it?

Comment: Try to bind the Points of the Series: `chart.Series[0].Points.Databind??(DataSource);`